# Explain for DB2 in IBM Data Server Manager fails

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

I am using the SQL Editor in IBM Data Server Manager to execute queries against DB2. The query in question works fine. However, when I click "Explain" to generate the access plan I get

> "Access Plan Graph Cannot Be Generated"

and the diagnostic text is

> The SQL statement failed. Explanation: The SQL statement resulted in
>   an error with SQLCODE: -204 and SQLSTATE: 42704. User response: The
>   DB2 documentation contains more information about the SQLCODE and how
>   to resolve the error. "DB2ADMIN.TABLENAME" is an undefined name..
>   SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.66.46

The query is something like

```
select col1, col2 from tablename where pred=value
```

Why is it failing? What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code -204 hints at the tablename not being know ("undefined name"). It seems that even though a query runs successfully without using a fully qualified name (schemaname.tablename), the explain functionality in IBM Data Server Manager needs the full name to work.

Changing the query to "select col1, col2 from schemaname.tablename where pred=value" caused the explain to succeed and it shows a nice graph of the access plan.